# Why is angular js not working here

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have these code samples that i am currently working on trying to learn angular js it worked well before but now it is not working at all
can some one please help me to make it right 
//INDEX.HTML

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{main.titlex}}</h1>

        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="main.searchInput">
        </div>
         <p>{{main.searchInput}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//app.js

```
angular.module('app',[]);
```

//main.ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app').controller("MainController",function(){

    var vm = this;
    vm.titlex = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
    vm.searcInput ='';
});
```

Comment: Pass the scope parameter to the controller, _controller("MainController",function(**vm**){_

Comment: Whats not working? Is there any error that you can list?

Answer (score 1):

Here is working solution with vm approach

```js
angular.module('app',[]);

    angular.module('app').controller('MainController',function($scope){
        vm = this;
        vm.titlex = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
        vm.searchInput ='Initial Demo text'; //corrected variable spelling and added it to vm
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{main.titlex}}</h1> 
<!-- you can directly acceess model as above -->

        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="main.searchInput">
        </div>
         <p>{{main.searchInput}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @noob - refer above code snippet without using $scope variable

Answer (score 0):

Replace your controller code by this one :

```
angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.titlex = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
    $scope.searchInput = '';
});
```

Comment: Bad copy/paste. It's fine now.

Comment: Can you please specify the issue with using vm. approach.

Comment: @iLoveJS Just replace `$scope` by `vm`, see my comment on the question

Comment: thank you for our response 
it solved the double binding issue 

http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/angularjs-in-30-minutes-angularjs-tutorial/

this is the tutorial i am using currently is it incorrect ?

Comment: @Tushar Just look at the tutorial. Thats my question, scope is not at all required in the controller as syntax which is used in the tutorial. So again the question why not vm. model.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't changed any code but your code looks like working fine..

```js
//app.js

angular.module('app',[]);
//main.ctrl.js

angular.module('app').controller("MainController",function(){

    var vm = this;
    vm.titlex = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
    vm.searcInput ='';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{main.titlex}}</h1>

        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="main.searchInput">
        </div>
         <p>{{main.searchInput}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer updated below code snippet -

```js
angular.module('app',[]);

angular.module('app').controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){ //added scope here
    $scope.titlex = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
    $scope.searchInput ='Initial Demo text'; //corrected variable spelling and added it to scope
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="main.ctrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{titlex}}</h1> 
<!-- you can directly acceess model as above -->

        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchInput">
        </div>
         <p>{{searchInput}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!!